# problems with module locations in codeigniter 3 hmvc

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a project which got several subfolders under Module folder, such as:

1. modules

   - List Management

     - app

       - model
       - view
       - controller
       - config

In cofig file, I set up module location like this,

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/'                   => '../modules/',
);
```

I set up my route like this

```
$route['app'] = 'app';
```

This route is not working, which shows CodeIgniter **404 error page not found**.

Answer (score 0):

because your folder structure is wrong

it should be

```
/modules/listmanagement/
/modules/listmanagement/controllers
/modules/listmanagement/models
/modules/listmanagement/views

/modules/listmanagement/controllers/app
```

Comment: sorry, can you explain me why its wrong...I have seen some other developers using file structure same as me..

Comment: i proposed you the solution ... after your first module folder you need the mvc folders - and after that you can build your own subfolders

Comment: I followed your instruction..but its still not working.

Comment: not sure what you mean with _its not working_, but if you call in your browser `your_url/listmanagement/app/your_function/` it should work...